# Is there a way to apply Convex Hull geometry node on disconnected meshes separately?

Tags: node-editor, instances, geometry-nodes

I have instances on points and some manipulations with them, so that the instance meshes are geometrically different. Is there a way to apply Convex Hull on each instance separately, or on realized geometries? Maybe using Mesh Island or Accumulate Field?

Comment: Thinking from the right side, since *Convex Hull* node outputs a single hull, how would you then combine an arbitrary number of geometries with a constant (unlike in Chris'es answer) setup of nodes... I don't see a way.

Comment: Wouldn't a _Geometry to Instances_ (plural) node be nice... grouping by some attribute (typically, mesh-island)

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use this node setup:

[image]

node group:

[image]

result:

[image]

starting geometry:

just a subdivided cube:

[image]

result:

[image]

> Note: you have to add as many nodegroups-nodes as you have mesh
> islands minus 1.

Comment: The way I read it, it applies convex hull only on the first cube, no? And the node layout depends on the number of islands? I'd multiply the middle points positions by x < 1 to make it clearly concave, and then test.

Comment: you are totally right...i forgot the convex hull node in the nodegroup...sorry. i updated my answer